# Utilizando Laravel 4 com Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: laravel, freetds, sql-server, pdoexception

Preciso conectar um banco SQL Server 2008 no Laravel 4. Andei pesquisando e não encontrei solução para o cenário em que me encontro.

Estou usando o Laravel utilizando o pacote XAMPP (PHP 5.5.6 --with-mssql) no **MAC OS X 10.9** com o FreeTDS funcionando perfeitamente quando utilizo as funções mssql_* do php em outras aplicações onde não utilizo o Laravel.

Quando faço uma consulta simples ao BD SQL recebo o seguinte erro:

> PDOException: could not find driver

Minha configuração em **/app/database.php** está desta forma:

```php
'default' => 'sqlsrv',

'sqlsrv' => array(      'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',         'host'     => 'ip do servidor',         'database' => 'nome da base',       'username' => 'sa',         'password' => 'senha',      'prefix'   => '',   ),
```

**[Editado]**

No php.ini, descomentei a linha:

```php
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
```

Porém, verificando a documentação do PHP encontrei a informação: "The PDO_SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows. For Linux, see ODBC and » Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux.", ou seja tenho que usar a conexão através de um Driver ODBC? Sera que não posso utilizar o FreeTDS no Laravel?

Atualizei o Native Client no Server com o SQL 2008 para a versão 11.

Continuo ainda sem sucesso.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: No `phpinfo()`, a extensão PDO_SQLSRV aparece habilitada?

Comment: Não. No phpinfo() -> API Extensions, aparecem apenas: mysqli,mysql,pdo_mysql.

Comment: Está ai o problema, ou está a extensão está comentada no seu php.ini, ou não está instalada.

Comment: Eu descomentei a linha extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll, porém o mssql nao aparece na lista de PDO's no phpinfo()

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro? a dll esta na pasta `ext`?

Comment: Não recebo nenhuma mensagem de erro quando inicio o Apache...

Comment: Não adianta tentar usar DLL no OSX. Eu acho que você vai precisar recompilar o php...

Comment: Tentando ajudar (em inglês): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371281/how-can-i-connect-to-sql-server-from-a-mac-with-php-pdo

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto, seu comentario me esclareceu algumas coisas e acho que estou próximo de encontrar a solução. Alguém ja esteve na mesma situação que isso e solicitou alterações no [Repositório do Laravel no Git](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/770). Agora preciso descobrir como o Laravel 4 manipula esses parâmetros na config do DB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depois de quase duas semanas de batalha, eis que consegui resolver a questão!

Tentei de diversas formas instalar o driver correto para fazer com que a conexão com o banco pudesse ser estabelecida. Fui até as [profundezas](http://www.acloudtree.com/how-to-install-freetds-and-unixodbc-on-osx-using-homebrew-for-use-with-ruby-php-and-perl/) em busca de instalar manualmente a pdodblib e fazer com que o PHP entendesse que precisaria chamar o FreeTDS através de uma conexão ODBC para conectar ao banco. Sem sucesso!

Até que uma luz apareceu no fim do túnel: um simples post [neste blog](http://www.ziqijin.com/setting-up-php-mssql-and-pdo_dblib-for-mac-osx-new-version/) parecia zombar de mim... Mas na verdade ele me trouxe uma simples solução.

Através do HomeBrew adicionei dois repositórios contendo as 'Formules' necessárias para re-compilar o PHP com suporte a MSSQL.

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
```

E depois...

```
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
```

Agora precisamos instalar o PHP através do comando:

```
brew install php55 --with-mssql
```

Após completar a instalação de todas as dependencias, basta que você configure o seu freetds.conf com as informações do banco e... Voilá! It works.

Answer (score 1):

Dei uma olhada rápida no Google e, de acordo com o stackoverflow em inglês, o teu **SQL SERVER NATIVE CLIENT** deve ser, no mínimo, a versão 11, para poder funcionar com o PDO.
Dá uma olahda nisso.

FONTE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213907/how-to-use-sql-server-connection-in-laravel

**EDIT:**
Também, é sempre bom dar uma olhada na documentação do PHP sobre o PDO + SQL SERVER - http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Comment: Eu já havia visto estes posts no Stack em Inglês, e por desencargo de consciência fui verificar:
Como comentei acima, realmente a PDO nao aparece no phpinfo(). 
Atualizei o Native Client do Server e continuo com o mesmo problema.